# Seprate movie name and year from moviefile name

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a file name like this

> Birdman.2014.DVDSCR.X264-PLAYNOW.mkv
>
> Divergent (2014) 720p Blu-Ray x2649 [Dual-Audio][English DD 5.1 +
>   Hindi DD 5.1] - Mafiaking - TeamTNT ExClusive.mkv
>
> Cradle 2 The Grave 2003 HDTVRip 720p Dual-Audio[Eng+Hindi] ~ BRAR

I have to seperated movie name and year

For getting year in use perg_match like

```
$s="Divergent (2014) 720p Blu-Ray x2649 [Dual-Audio][English DD 5.1 + Hindi DD 5.1] - Mafiaking - TeamTNT ExClusive.mkv";
     if (preg_match('/\b\d{4}\b/', $s, $matches)) {
    $year = $matches[0];
}
echo $year;
```

> result :- 2014 //working perfect

But I also want to get movie name like

> Divergent
>
> Birdman
>
> Cradle 2 The Grave

I also check with this link

[Extracting movie name and year from string were year is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400425/extracting-movie-name-and-year-from-string-were-year-is-optional)

But nothing happen

How i get it? Please help or provide hint to achive it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^.+?(?=\s*[(.]?(\d{4}))
```

You can try this.The movie name will be in match and year in the first group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vA0yQ3/2

```
$re = "/^.+?(?=\\s*[(.]?(\\d{4}))/mi"; 
$str = "\n\nBirdman.2014.DVDSCR.X264-PLAYNOW.mkv\n\nDivergent (2014) 720p Blu-Ray x2649 [Dual-Audio][English DD 5.1 + Hindi DD 5.1] - Mafiaking - TeamTNT ExClusive.mkv\n\nCradle 2 The Grave 2003 HDTVRip 720p Dual-Audio[Eng+Hindi] ~ BRAR\n"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Let me try it

Comment: excellent sir !! With this expression i am getting year and name in both. Thanka for your help.

Comment: How would one get this to work for a title like: Blade.Runner.2049.2017.2160p.US.BluRay.REMUX.HEVC.DTS-HD.MA.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-FGT

Comment: @StuyvesantBlue  something like this https://regex101.com/r/pbRKJq/1