# Get title and year from file name using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a regex that gets title and, if available, year from filenames? See examples below.

This solution works for php but im having problem translating it into javascript 
[Seprate movie name and year from moviefile name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369085/seprate-movie-name-and-year-from-moviefile-name)

```
 The.Great.Gatsby.2013.BluRay.1080p.DTS.x264-CHD.mkv
 The Forbidden Girl 2013 BRRIP Xvid AC3-BHRG.avi
 Pain.&.Gain.2013.720p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-HiDt.mkv
 Se7en.avi
 Se7en.(1995).avi
 How to train your dragon 2.mkv
 10,000BC (2010).1080p.avi
```

Comment: This is not trivial because a title could contain a year or the name of the format.

Comment: This sounds like it is being used for 100% legal purposes.

Comment: Can you describe the pattern the regex should look for?

Comment: without a context free grammar to reference, any solution will probably have a lot of edge cases missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution provided below works for all the test cases you provided (and some extra as the titlelize, see the code below) and is intended to be customizable.

Long story short, try the **snippet below**:

```js
// Live Test
var input  = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
input.oninput = function() { output.textContent = extractData(input.value); }

// Samples
var tests = ['The.Great.Gatsby.2013.BluRay.1080p.DTS.x264-CHD.mkv', 'The Forbidden Girl 2013 BRRIP Xvid AC3-BHRG.avi', 'Pain.&.Gain.2013.720p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-HiDt.mkv', 'Se7en.(1995).avi', 'How to train your dragon 2.mkv', '10,000BC (2010).1080p.avi', 'The.Great.Gatsby.BluRay.1080p.DTS.x264-CHD.mkv', 'Se7en.avi', '2001 A Space Odyssey.BluRay.1080p.DTS.x264-CHD.mkv','Sand.Castle.2017.FRENCH.1080.WEBRip.AAC2.0-NEWCiNE-WwW.Zone-Telechargement.Ws.mkv'];

while (t = tests.pop()) {
   document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += '<b>INPUT</b>: "' + t + '"<br>';
   document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += extractData(t,true) + '<hr>';
}

function titlelize(title) {
   return title.replace(/(^|[. ]+)(\S)/g, function(all, pre, c) { return ((pre) ? ' ' : '') + c.toUpperCase(); });
};

function extractData(it, html) {
   var regex = /^(.+?)[.( \t]*(?:(19\d{2}|20(?:0\d|1[0-9])).*|(?:(?=bluray|\d+p|brrip|webrip)..*)?[.](mkv|avi|mpe?g|mp4)$)/i;

   var out = '&#8627;&nbsp;';
   
   if ( m = regex.exec(it) ) {
       title = titlelize(m[1]) || '-'; year = m[2] || '-';
       out += '<font color="green"><b>Title</b>: "' + title + 
          '"&emsp; <b>Year</b>: "' + year + '"</font>';
   } else {
       out += '<font color="red">No match</font>';
   }
   //the replace is an hack to remove html in live input text
   return (html) ? out : out.replace(/<[^>]+>|&[^;]+;/g,'');
}
```

```html
<mark><b>Paste and Try!</b></mark> &rArr; <input id="input" type="text" size="70" />
<br>&#8627;&emsp;<span id="output" style="line-height:40px;">No Match</span>
<hr>

<div id="list"></div>
```

**Description**

Assuming the title is structured roughly as this:

> **Title*** || [ **Year*** ] || [ **Codec** ] **Extension**
>   
>  The fields enclosed in square brackets are optional (e.g [**field1**])
>   
> *** :** field saved

The key is to match everything as **title** till the last valid **year** found (valid years: 1900-2016)  or till the file **extension** (structured as a dot plus 3 letters, simple to change if needed).

*Exceptions*: in the case where a film does not contain a valid year at all the section starting with (case insensitive) `bluray` or `[0-9]+p` (e.g. `720p`, `1080p`) or `brrip` is stripped from the **title** section.

**Regex Breakout**   <kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jL7yJ7/9)</kbd>

```
/^
  (.+?)                           # Save title into group $1
  [.( \t]*                        # Remove some separators
  (?:                             # Non capturing group
    (19\d{2}|20(?:0\d|1[0-6])).*  # Save years (1900-2016) in $2
  |                               # OR
    (?:(?=bluray|\d+p|brrip)..*)? # Match string starting with bluray,brrip,720p...
    [.](mkv|avi|mpe?g)$)          # Match extension (.mkv,.avi.,mpeg) add your own
/i                                # make the regex case insensitive
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Regex Customization**

The list of *exceptions* and *extensions* can be easily filled with new values little by little during tests when/if needed (as file extension, e.g. to add `.wmv` and `.flv` add them to the `(mkv|avi|mpe?g|wmv|flv)` section of the regex) or to make the section generic replace it with `[.]\w{3,4}$`.

Comment: And when the title contains a number?

Comment: @epascarello: the first example ``Se7en.avi`` contains a number :) Only the last number of the string is taken as the ``year`` and only if is between ``1900-2016`` and if preceded by something, so ``2001 A Space Odyssey.mkv`` is parsed correctly. There is a live demo inside the answer, you can try by yourself!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_2000 is an example of a movie with a number that would cause an issue. Just saying there are some outliers in the naming schema of the files. (unless my brain is missing something)

Comment: @epascarello: you're right but this is the expected behaviour: we can't know without a pre-knowledge that this is not a "Dracula" film of the 2000 (also because actually it's a film of the 2000 :) ). Since there is no regular structure the best we can do is an heuristic that try to minimize the outliers.

Comment: @OlivierAlbertini: thank you for your update. I've updated the regex in the answer accordingly.